# user defined variable in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, variables, procedure

I'm trying to create a data abstraction in SQL where I can choose the quarter I want to look at for my employee info. Right now I'm using the naming system Q1_P1_N for "Quarter 1 Project 1 name" and Q1_P1_W is "...project 1 weight." Employees can work on multiple projects.
So far what I have is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE effort_lookup4(IN proj_name VARCHAR(20), IN quarter INT(1))
BEGIN
SET @Qx_P1_N = CONCAT('Q', quarter, '_P1_N');
SET @Qx_P2_N = CONCAT('Q', quarter, '_P2_N');
SET @Qx_P1_W = CONCAT('Q', quarter, '_P1_W');
SET @Qx_P2_W = CONCAT('Q', quarter, '_P2_W');
SET @var1 = (SELECT sum(@Qx_P1_W) FROM table_test WHERE @Qx_P1_N = proj_name);
SET @var2 = (SELECT sum(@Qx_P2_W) FROM table_test WHERE @Qx_P2_N = proj_name);
```

My problem is that whenever I call a query with @Qx_P1_N or @Qx_P1_W I'm not actually passing the correct query in and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. This should be pretty easy I'm just new to using SQL.

Here's an example of what the table looks like, except it carries on into Q2_P1_N and so on through the quarters:

```
+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| EMPID| Q1_P1_N | Q1_P2_N | Q1_P1_W | Q1_P2_W |
+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 1000 | ProjA   | ProjB   |    0.50 |    0.50 |
| 1001 | ProjA   | NULL    |    1.00 |    NULL |
| 1010 | ProjB   | NULL    |    1.00 |    NULL |
| 1011 | ProjA   | ProjB   |    0.50 |    0.50 |
+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I'm entirely following the question.  Could you show sample data from `table_test`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you want with your existing data structure requires that you use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) (you build your desired `SELECT` statement as a string that you then `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`).

However, you will probably find it easier to change your data structure:

```
+------+---------+---------+--------+
| EMPID| quarter | project | weight |
+------+---------+---------+--------+
| 1000 |       1 | A       |   0.50 |
| 1000 |       1 | B       |   0.50 |
| 1001 |       1 | A       |   1.00 |
| 1010 |       1 | B       |   1.00 |
| 1011 |       1 | A       |   0.50 |
| 1011 |       1 | B       |   0.50 |
+------+---------+---------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand what data structure you are suggesting, the only problem is that with that the structure becomes very inefficiency, which is a problem because I am trying to eventually index over 1000 employees.

Comment: @NateSHolland: MySQL can easily handle that - it's not inefficient at all.  Just make sure you build appropriate indexes.

Comment: So then what happens when I want to look at what projects employee 1000 is on?

Comment: @NateSHolland: How do you mean?  You would just `SELECT ... WHERE EMPID = 1000`, no?

Comment: Yea you're right, I looked at it and I think your data structure is better

Answer (score 0):

On your select statement you have a variable in the field that should be the column name in the table.  You will need to switch the @Qx_P1_W  for Q1_P1_W.

Comment: But the point is that I want to be able to make the column a variable that I can change so I can choose which quarter I'm looking at